# when using routeparams in angular,templateurl not working?

Tags: html, angularjs

https://plnkr.co/edit/oo05d6H6AxuJGXBAUQvr?p=preview

I have created an array of items and when I click on each item details page will be displayed ,for all the items in the array I have used same details page,can anyone look at my plunker and explain why the templateURL is not working when I click on an item?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.controller('mobileController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Iphone',
  }, {
    name: 'Oneplus'
  }, {
    name: 'Moto'
  }];
});
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/item/:itemName', {
      templateUrl: 'details.html',
      controller: 'ItemCtrl'
    });
app.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.itemName = $routeParams.itemName;

  }
]);
});
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mobileController">
<h2> Welcome to Mobile Store</h2>  
<p>Search:<input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in items|filter:test"><a href="/items/{{item}}">{{ item.name }}</a>
  </li>

</ul>

<div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my details page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  {{itemName}}
```

Comment: Plenty of issues here, mostly typos. All fixed here ~ https://plnkr.co/edit/rKHsBMFcXqJUGp8Blx7Q?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! If I have to add a image attribute in the array how to provide it?

Answer (score 1):

is it because of a mismatch?

.when('/item/:itemName', {

a href="/item**s**/{{item}}"

there's an extra s there

Comment: This is definitely **one** of the problems

Answer (score 1):

Summary of problems:

1. Your `ItemCtrl` is currently defined inside your module's `config` function. Move it out of there

   ```
   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/item/:itemName', {
         templateUrl: 'details.html',
         controller: 'ItemCtrl'
       });
   }); // you were missing this    

   app.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
   ```
2. Your route is `/item/:itemName` and since you're not using HTML5 mode, you need to create your `href` attributes with a `#` prefix. For example

   ```
   ng-href="#/item/{{item.name}}"
   ```

Fixed demo here ~ https://plnkr.co/edit/rKHsBMFcXqJUGp8Blx7Q?p=preview